# Mysql, ver ultima fecha de pago de una tabla y datos de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, date

Se que es un pregunta algo recurrente, pero no la he podido resolver todavia.
Tengo un sistema de clinica con pacientes y estos presentan a otros, asi se les hace un descuento al mes siguiente en su cuota mensual. Pero para el descuento, los pacientes que yo presento deben estar al día en sus cuotas. Tengo dos tablas:
[image: Tabla Pacientes]

Y otra:

[image: tabla cuota]

deseo que el listado sea el siguiente:

[image: Listado deseado]

Para ello lo intente con el siguiente código sql:

`SELECT c.id, c.pid, concat(p.apellido, ', ', p.nombre) pnombre, p.documento, c.importe, c.fecha FROM cuotas c LEFT JOIN paciente p ON c.pid = p.pid  WHERE p.presentado_por = '40' AND c.fecha = (SELECT MAX(c2.fecha) FROM cuota c2 WHERE c2.pid = '40')`

Pero me lista solo un paciente.
Muchas gracias y saludos a todos.
Luis.

Comment: Hola, si la respuesta te fue util podrias marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.pid, concat(p.apellido, ', ', p.nombre) as NombreApellidos, p.documento, c2.Importe, c2.Fecha as UltimoPago
from
(select max(id) as id, pid
 from cuotas
 group by pid)c inner join pacientes p on c.pid = p.pid
inner join cuotas c2 on c2.id = c.id
```

La consulta interior dentro de la **cláusula** **from**:

```
select max(id) as id, pid
 from cuotas
 group by pid
```

Va a a agrupar por el **campo** **pid** de la **tabla** **cuotas** y por cada grupo nos va a devolver el que tenga el mayor **id**, ya que el mayor **id**  es la última fecha de pago, es decir es el registro más reciente.

Posteriormente a esta consulta le hacemos un **inner join** con la **tabla** **paciente** y a la propia **tabla cuotas** para obtener todos los campos que queramos.

En tu ejemplo filtras por los que tengan el **campo** **presentado_por = 40** para hacerlo con este filtro en la cláusula interior tendrías que poner:

```
select p.id, p.pid, concat(p.apellido, ', ', p.nombre) as NombreApellidos, p.documento, c2.Importe, c2.Fecha as UltimoPago
from
(select max(id) as id, pid
 from cuotas
 group by pid)c inner join pacientes p on c.pid = p.pid
inner join cuotas c2 on c2.id = c.id
 where p.presentado_por = 40
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, es usted muy amable y entiendo sobre la consulta interior a que se refiere, pero me da error que es sobre los alias, pero que no puedo arreglar:  Error SQL (1054) Unknow column 'c.importe' in 'fiel list'

Comment: @LuisAngelUriarte, revisa ahora, arreglado

Comment: Muchas gracias migo, me sigue dando el mismo error (estoy ejecutando su ultimo script). Mi servidor..:  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.28-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: @LuisAngelUriarte, revisa ahora

Comment: **¡Aplauso!... ¡Aplauso! ¡Aplauso!...** Muchas gracias mi amigo... eres un genio. El script esta perfecto, justo lo que buscaba

Comment: @LuisAngelUriarte , si l respuesta te fue útil podrías marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto,  gracias